# Difference between assert and assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, assertions

I am writing a test case in rails Minitest, I have two scenarios, first one is :

```
 assert_select "button.btn[type=submit]", I18n.t('pay_and_post_job')
```

But when i run this then i get an error

> Expected at least 1 element matching "button.btn[type=submit]", found
>   0..
>           Expected 0 to be >= 1.

But if i write the same assertion as :

```
 assert "button.btn[type=submit] #{I18n.t('pay_and_post_job')}"
```

Then test is passing

Can someone explain this to me what exactly is happening??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`assert` and `assert_select` are from two very different toolkits. The first being very general and only tests if its first argument is a true value. `assert "button"` will always pass as `"button"` is truthy.

On the other hand [`assert_select`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/SelectorAssertions.html#method-i-assert_select) is from Rails and tests your html output. Try reducing the test statement until it passes, if `assert_select "[type=submit]"` is still failing you some bug in your template. My bet is that `assert_select "input.btn[type=submit]"` will pass.

Comment: You are right actually i was making a mistake, In the view this was an input field and not a button field , now its passing